# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"Он постоянно задается вопросом "кто (—) кого?" — требуется ли тут тире или нет? В оригинале оно стояло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

КТО КОГО - устойчивое выражение. Тире не ставится. Если подходить к вопросу формально, то тире объясняется отсутствием предиката, на месте которого тире и поставлено: кто [победит] кого.